# How set 0 with MAX function when it is NULL?

Tags: mysql, null, max, zero

I would like to understand how to set 0 value of the attribute when it is NULL with MAX function. For example:

```
Name columns:
number - date

Values:
10 - 2012-04-04
11 - 2012-04-04
12 - 2012-04-04
13 - 2012-04-15
14 - 2012-06-21
 1 - 2013-07-04
```

Number is incremental field, but it has set itself 1 when new year has come.
But result of:

```
SELECT (MAX(number)+1) number WHERE date LIKE "2014%"
```

is NULL and not 1 because MAX(number) is NULL and not 0

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Well, as there is no date like 2014, you would expect null, because the maximum of nothing is actually not anyting.

But do this:

```
COALESCE(MAX(number),0)
```

Which means: get the first non-null thing from the next list, so if your `max` is null, it'll give you `0`

Comment: Its mysql standard which shows output `null` when there is no result is found not `0`.
You can use `COALESCE(MAX(number),0)` like `Nanne` is telling you.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I think you replied on the wrong answer xD

Comment: (Oracle) "Group function is not allowed here"… unfortunately.

Answer (score 29):

COALESCE works, but [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) seems clearer to me.

```
IFNULL(MAX(number), 0)
```

If the first expression is not NULL, IFNULL() returns the expression itself, otherwise it returns the second parameter.
IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Comment: Note that `COALESCE` is part of SQL standard with a well defined behavior, `IFNULL` is MySQL specific.