# How do I select SQL data in buckets when data doesn't exist for one bucket?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, sum

I'm trying to get a **complete set of buckets for a given dataset, even if no records exist for some buckets**.

For example, I want to display totals by day of week, with zero total for days with no records.

```
SELECT
WEEKDAY(transaction_date) AS day_of_week,
SUM(sales) AS total_sales
FROM table1
GROUP BY day_of_week
```

If I have sales every day, I'll get 7 rows in my result representing total sales on days 0-6.

If I don't have sales on Day 2, I get no result for Day 2.

**What's the most efficient way to force a zero value for day 2?**

Should I join to a temporary table or array of defined buckets? ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6']

Or is it better to insert zeros outside of MySQL, after I've done the query?

I am using MySQL, but this is a general SQL question.

Comment: No - there are no "general" sql questions. WEEKDAY doesn't exist in tsql - so right off the bat you can't apply your query to just any database engine. There is a general technique to apply here (you need a "list" of all buckets you desire) but the actual sql best suited for your engine depends on the engine. And "better" is something that cannot be measured. You ask a sql-based question, you will get SQL-based responses. Is it "better" to do this in the code that consumes the resultset? Only you can really answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you could simply use a derived table of numbers from `1` to `7`, `left join` it with the table, then aggregate:

```
select d.day_of_week, sum(sales) AS total_sales
from (
    select 1 day_of_week union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
    union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
) d
left join table1 t1 on weekday(t1.transaction_date) = d.day_of_week
group by day_of_week
```

Very recent versions have the `values(row...)` syntax, which shortens the query:

```
select d.day_of_week, sum(sales) AS total_sales
from (values row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6), row(7)) d(day_of_week)
left join table1 t1 on weekday(t1.transaction_date) = d.day_of_week
group by day_of_week
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want the answer to be 0 when the data is actually null for that bucket, therefore you want the max(null, 0). A max function wouldn't natively work with NULL in this way, however, you can use COALESCE to force it:

`COALESCE(MAX(SUM(sales)),0)`

as suggested by  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10172205/4028718)

Answer (score 1):

First off you need a calendar table; something like [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) or [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/). Or create calendar subset on the fly. I am not sure of the mySQL syntax, but here is what it would look like in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE
    @FromDate DATE
  , @ToDate   DATE

-- set these variables to appropriate values
SET @FromDate = '2020-03-01';
SET @ToDate = '2020-03-31';

;WITH cteCalendar (MyDate) AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @FromDate) AS MyDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, MyDate)
    FROM   cteCalendar
    WHERE  DATEADD(DAY, 1, MyDate) <= @ToDate
)
SELECT WEEKDAY(cte.MyDate) AS day_of_week,
SUM(sales) AS total_sales
FROM cteCalendar cte
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON cte.MyDate = t1.transaction_date
GROUP BY day_of_week
```

Comment: In my case, I know I only want the numbers 1 to 7 (representing days) so I don't need the calendar - but good solution for a more complex problem